# Мало приложений в Ubuntu Software

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-software

После установки убунты 16.04, в магазине приложений мало программ. Нет ни хромиума, ни скайпа. Показаны только те, которые уже установлены. С интернетом проблем нет, система только после установки. Как можно решить данную проблему?

В "Программы и обновления". Первые 4 галки стоят.

В папке /etc/apt/sources.list.d нет файлов

Содержимое файла /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

# See htt p://help. ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src ht tp://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb ht tp://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb ht tp://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src htt p://ru. archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb htt p://archive. canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src htt p://archive .canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src htt p://security. ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: приведите прямо в вопросе содержимое файла `/etc/apt/sources.list` и всех файлов в каталоге `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Так же можно воспользоваться графическим интерфейсом. Откройте настройки системы, далее выберите пункт "Программы и обновления". Проверьте, чтобы на первой вкладке стояли первые 4 галки

Comment: Хм… может быть кеш пакетов не обновлён. Попробуйте выполнить в терминале команду `apt update`. А вообще, apt'ом вручную ставятся какие либо пакеты?

Comment: На всякий случай проверьте, что в меню "Вид" установлен переключатель "Все приложения" https://imgur.com/dbMFeib

Answer (score 2):

Для установки именно `Google Chrome` надо добавить официальный репозиторий:

```
sudo -i

echo -e '\n \e[1;36m' Добавляется репозиторий Google Chrome '\e[0m \n'
echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub -O - | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

`Skype` есть в партнёрском репозитории. Он у тебя в листинге:

```
# deb http://archive. canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Строку надо раскоментировать и тоже обновить индекс пакетов через `sudo apt-get update`

А ещё официальный `flash player` лежит в виде пакета `adobe-flash-properties-gtk`.

UPD про skype (теперь вообще [официальная](https://repo.skype.com) репа):

```
echo 'deb https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
wget -O - https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install skypeforlinux -y
```

Comment: немного ошибаетесь по поводу adobe flash. adobe-flash-properties-gtk      - GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player. adobe-flashplugin               - Adobe Flash Player plugin

Comment: Да, небольшая очепятка.

Answer (score 1):

Как я помню хром отказался от поддержки 32 битной версии И удалил все chrome из репозитория, его тама нету как и репозитория. Используйте chromium это практически тоже самое что и chrome(даже так, chrome это надстройки над chromium), + он открытый.

Про скайп не знаю, не пользуюсь. Все зависит от репозиториев.